# C# wpf List: How to enumerate n level List<>

Tags: c#, wpf, list, enumeration

A class System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Model3DGroup : Model3D

If I've done

```
  ...
  model3DGroup1.Add(model3DGroup0);
  model3DGroup2.Add(model3DGroup1);
  model3DGroup3.Add(model3DGroup2);
  model3DGroup4.Add(model3DGroup3);
  ...
  model3DGroupN.Add(model3DGroupN_Minus_One);
```

How will I enumerate these N level **Model3DGroup** s form `model3DGroupN` if above code is not known to me? How to know the per level child elements? The number of childs may not be one.

Comment: You should have a list of lists, rather than n lists each ending with a different number...

Comment: Model3DGroup is inherited from ILIST ICOLLECTION only. So its list only.

Comment: Anyone.. please give any hint.

Comment: Can I get each lists reference while adding them and using some property I modify those and the change will reflect in the original value?

Comment: Sorry to ask so simple question. As in C I can have references. How in C#? :P

Comment: In C# all classes are reference types, so they are effectively already pointers to objects, rather than objects themsevles, as opposed to `struct` types, which are value types, rather than references to objects.  So in short, you don't need to do anything; it's already done.

Comment: Really .. I am tying it now. .. Thanks for being so super fast.

Comment: Hey, doing this way model looses its initial placement. But maintains its 'child'ish behavior. Pointer stuff worked though. Now I've to work on maintaining its initial transforms. ??!!